# Double Behavior Of Magic Methods __set() and __get() with property_exists() function and without it

Tags: php, oop, getter-setter, magic-methods

I am trying to understand Magic functions in a class and while I was testing  __set() and __get() methods.
CODE:

```
class kids{
 
 private $height;
 public function __set($property, $value){
//if(property_exists($this, $property))
      $this->property= $value; //this works
}

 public function __get($property){
 return "The child's height is " . $this->$property . " inches tall";
  }

}
$kid1= new kids;

$kid1->height= 45;

echo $kid1->height;
```

OUTPUT :

```
The child's height is 45 inches tall
```

MY PROBLEM:

the output is correct but if I uncomment `if(property_exists($this, $property))`  then __set is called twice and it doesn't change the value of height unless I write it like this `$this->$property= $value;` adding $ to `$this->property`.

OUTPUT with property_exists() :

```
 The child's height is inches tall
```

I tried googling the problem but what I found was that  The property_exists() function cannot detect properties that are magically accessible using the __get magic method. I don't understand this note.
If someone can shed light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With `$this->property= $value;` I get the output `The child's height is  inches tall` as `$this->property` refers to a property with the name `property`.  `$this->$property= $value;` works in your above code.

Comment: [Your original snippet's output (with the `property_exists`) check doesn't show "45" either.](https://3v4l.org/vDX0H), for the reason Nigel (and yourself) pointed out. So I guess you mixed some things up.